# In Apache Solr does position semantically mean the same thing as order?

Tags: solr

In Apache Solr if I have two fields from two different documents:

field 1: "tom sawyer was a character in huckleberry finn"

field 2: "a character in huckleberry finn is tom sawyer"

*note that for simplicity the fields don't appear tokenized as shown here, but they are in the index

And I search for "a character in huckleberry finn," (also tokenized) will field 2 score higher because not only are the tokens in the same *order* in the field as they are in the query, but the *position* of the phrase in the text is at the beginning in both the field and in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The positions are not used for computing the score, except for the positions in relation to each other if you use a phrase query. In your example, they're the same - so the score should be identical.

To avoid having a post for each similar question that you should have, it's probably better to refer to the [Lucene Practical Scoring Formula](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html) which shows how the score is actually calculated for the TFIDF similarity. Remember that the similarity calculation is pluggable, so if you're using a different similarity, the calculation will be different.

These items are also simple to test by yourself - just index two documents with the text and issue a query with `debugQuery` set to true - and you'll see how each element contributes to the score.